# How to create system notifications for Macbook Prof / MacOS

Tags: macos, macbook, notifications, applescript

For Ubuntu it's easy to create a desktop notification:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/187022/how-can-i-send-a-custom-desktop-notification

it looks like:

```
$ notify-send "Hello world!"
```

on MacOS, I am looking for a simple command that I can use to create a system notification. Is there some apple script that I can launch to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `display notification` in Applescript. For example:

```
osascript -e 'display notification "Hello World!" with title "Notification Example"'
```

The Applescript documentation for [Displaying Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayNotifications.html) has additional details.

Comment: happen to know if there are C bindings that can be used, instead of launching a child process?